# How can I get image from closed group which I joined using GraphAPI

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api

I already try this but seems like it's not work on Facebook Graph API with newest version.

http://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ALBUM_ID/photos?fields=picture,source,name&type=uploaded

I don't manage that group, I just join into that, but how can I get image from that group ?

Please help

Comment: i don´t think you can get anything from closed groups you don´t manage. try with a group you manage, or with a public group.

Comment: Sadly :( The problem is I don't manage that group. If I manage that, I can get all data I want :'( No way to do that ?

Comment: i don´t think so. think about it this way: if you manage a closed (or even secret) group, would you want any member to be able to grab all the content in the group without your knowledge? ;)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:** You can access all data from an Closed Group or Secret Group if you joined this group by using **Full Token Permission**

You can go to your profile pages, then press **Ctrl + U** to view page source, then you find **"access_token"** in pages source and you will see an access token with format in **"EAAAAU"** at the begining. You can try with this access token then you can get all data from API as usual.